# Which colour comes out first from a prism?

Tags: optics, refraction, spectroscopy

[image]When a narrow beam of white light is incident on a triangular prism. The speed of red light is maximum and violet is of minimum, red light bends less and travels less distance as compared to violet light. From this can I say that red light comes out first from the prism. Is this true?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: im right or wrong, about what i asked because i teach to students, i want to conform before i teach it.

Comment: I think you need to define the geometry of the problem before anyone can provide an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "red light comes out first", when your illumination is a continuous beam of light? Your answer holds for the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) of the light, but that's not the speed at which e.g. a light pulse would propagate (that's the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity)) or anything recognizable as the speed at which energy moves inside the medium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to calculate the amount of time a red photon spends traveling through the prism, vs the amount of time a blue photon spends, then you need to calculate the distance traveled (using trigonometry and the shape of the prism and angle of the illumination beam), divide by the speed of light, and multiply by the refractive index. Note that the refractive index depends on the wavelength (color).

Comment: From the above figure, can I say that red light comes out first

Comment: If the figure is correct, it's easy to see that red light travels the shortest distance.  It also experiences the lowest refractive index (based on the refracted angles shown), so yes, from a very short pulse of white light entering the prism, the red would exit first.  But that is only because of the angle of the exit face of the prism.  If the exit face were tilted enough, the blue could come out first.